# URL Routing in Zend

Tags: zend-framework

So, I've just started using Zend, moving our companies internal CMS over onto the new Framework, and if you saw the existing code I'm sure you would soon agree the best way to to scrap the whole thing and start over.

So, thats exactly what I'm doing.  It's relatively small, so as projects go it shouldn't take too long. Anyhow, to get to the point:

**How exactly does routing work in Zend?**

I have created a project, and two Modules, one called "default" and one called "admin".  If you haven't guessed already I'd like the default module to be the front end of the site, and the admin module to be the backend of the site.  When I navigate to ~/public/ I can see the "Welcome to Zend Framework" screen, but when I navigate to ~/public/admin I just get a 404.

What am I missing to get this working?  Also, how do I map ~/ to ~/public/ where ~/ is the domain?

As a note, I made the modules and an Index controller within each using the zf tools on the command line using the following commands:

```
zf create Module default
zf create controller Index -m default
zf create Module admin
zf create controller Index -m admin
```

Thanks and advance for any help your able to give.

Dan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'public' should not be in your URLs. Change your vhost so that the document root points at the public folder, not the application root folder, that will probably solve your problem. If not, make sure you have a .htaccess file which includes the mod_rewrite rules as explained in the manual, but if you used the command line tool to generate the project that part is probably fine.

Comment: Thanks Tim.  I didn't realise it would effect Zend that badly, I figured it wouldn't be too much of an issue not pointing to vHost directly to it during development on a localhost.  I threw it up on a dev sub-domain overnight, and changed the vHost to point to the public folder as you said and it worked perfectly.  Thanks!